# How can I convert 2 row into column in tsql?

Tags: sql, t-sql, row

I have 2 row data which I want to make it to be 2 column,
I tried union syntax but it didn't work.
Here is the data I have:

> breed 1 breed2

I tried to convert it with this sql

```
select a.breed union a.breed
```

but it didn't work.

Here is what you want from the SQL:

> breed1,breed2

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: Extend to 7 or 8 rows of data, then show us the sample data and the expected result.

Comment: search around for PIVOT

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  [breed1], 
  [breed2]]
FROM 
( 
  SELECT 'breed1' myColumn 
  union 
  select 'breed2' 
) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT 
( 
  AVG(mySecondColumn) FOR       
  myColumn IN ([breed1], [breed2]]) 
)   AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: If you believe that this is answer satisfies your need, please consider to check it as answer by clicking the green tick

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join. This needs a way to pair rows together (so if you have four rows you get 1 and 2 in one result and 3 and 4 in the other rather than another combination).

I'm going to assume you have sequentially numbered rows in an `Id` column and an odd numbered row is paired with the one greater even `Id`:

```
select odd.Data as 'First', even.Data as 'Second'
from TheData odd
    inner join TheData even on odd.Id+1 = even.Id
where odd.Id % 2 = 1;
```

More generally for more columns use of `pivot` is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

How about an aggregation query?

```
select min(breed) as breed1, max(breed) as breed2
from t;
```